# Processing each line to be stored as a structure

Tags: c, data-structures, io

I am writing a program which should do multiple things including prompting the user for the name of the input file which I have done, but I am having troubling implementing a process where the program processes each line from a file, storing it as a struct data structure, finally using the malloc, calloc commands it will store all the valid records in memory to be validated. So any help on how to do this would be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>          //library including standard input and output functions
#include <stdlib.h>         //library including exit and system functions used below
#include <string.h>         //library including string functions used

struct packet{
    int source;
    int destination;
    int type;               // Varibles for the structure
    int port;
    char data[50];
    char * filename;
};

int main ()
{
    printf("**************Details*******************************\n");
    printf("*****Student name: ***********************\n");
    printf("*****Course name: *******\n");
    printf("*****Student ID:  ************************ \n");
    printf("\n");

    // The program must prompt for the name of the input file. If it doesn't exist the program should stop with an error message


    FILE *DataFile;
    char filename[10] = { '\0' } ;
    char DataLine[70];

    printf("Enter the filename you wish to open\n");
    scanf("%s", &filename);

    if (( DataFile = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("*****file could not be opened. : %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    // Read the data from this file

    char *fgets(DataLine, 70, (FILE) *DataFile);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the text file the program should take the data from

```
0001:0002:0003:0021:CLS
0001:0010:0003:0021:CLS
0001:0002:0002:0080:<HTML>
0005:0002:0002:8080:<BR>
0005:0012:0002:8080:<BR>
0001:0002:0002:0080:<BODY>
0005:0002:0002:8080:<B>HELLO</B><BR>
0002:0004:0002:0090:100000000000000000022
0001:0002:0003:0021:DEL
0002:0004:0002:0010:100000000000000000023
```

Each colon from the file shows what part of the packet structure it should be a part of, i.e. the first set of 4 numbers is the "source" then "destination and so forth.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: call of `fgets` using `char *fgets(DataLine, 70, (FILE) *DataFile);` isn't looks strange?

Comment: posted code as it is should not even compile.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is :

- Use `fgets` to read the file line by line.
- For each line, use `strtok` to tokenize the string.
- For each of the first four tokens, use `strtol` to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

A.  The line `char *fgets(DataLine, 70, (FILE) *DataFile);` should probably just read `fgets(DataLine, 70, DataFile);`

B.  If you create a single variable you don't really need `malloc` since the compiler will allocate it, but if you are planning on creating an array of Data you will only need to call `malloc` once to create the whole array, something like:

```
struct packet* packetarr = malloc(sizeof packetarr * DESIRED_ARRAY_SIZE);
```

C.  As downHillFromHere suggested, use [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) to get each part of the string and [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) to convert the read strings to numbers when appropriate.